# Keeping track of winning die

Tags: java

So this is what I'm trying to do.
The program should have a loop that iterates 10 times. Each time the loop iterates, it should roll both dice. The die with the highest value wins. In the case of a tie, there is no winner for that particular roll of the dice.

As the loop iterates, the program should:

1. Ask the user if they are ready to roll.
2. Display the result of the roll
   The number of User’s roll, Computer’s roll, and the result (who win, lose or 
   tie).
3. Keep count of the number of times the computer wins.
4. Keep count of the number of times that the user wins

The Die object code:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
   The Die class simulates a six-sided die.
*/

public class Die
{
   private int sides;   // Number of sides
   private int value;   // The die's value

  /**
     The constructor performs an initial
     roll of the die.
     @param numSides The number of sides for this die.
  */

  public Die(int numSides)
  {
     sides = numSides;
     roll();
  }

  /**
     The roll method simulates the rolling of
     the die.
  */

  public void roll()
  {
     // Create a Random object.
     Random rand = new Random();

     // Get a random value for the die.
     value = rand.nextInt(sides) + 1;
  }

  /**
     getSides method
     @return The number of sides for this die.
  */

  public int getSides()
  {
     return sides;
  }

  /**
     getValue method
     @return The value of the die.
  */

  public int getValue()
  {
     return value;
  }
}
```

This is the code that uses the object code, for the dice and their movement.

```
public class MitchellLab06
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int DIE1_SIDES = 6; //Number of sides for die #1
        final int DIE2_SIDES = 6; //Number of sides for die #1
        final int MAX_ROLLS = 10; //Number of ties to roll

        // Create two instances of the Die class.
        Die die1 = new Die(DIE1_SIDES);
        Die die2 = new Die(DIE2_SIDES);

        //Display the initial value of the dice.
        System.out.println("This program simulates the rolling of a " + 
        DIE1_SIDES + " sided die and another " +
        DIE2_SIDES + " sided die.");

        System.out.println("The initial value of the dice:");
        System.out.println(die1.getValue() + " " + die2.getValue());

        //Roll the dice 10 times.
        System.out.println("Rolling the dice " + MAX_ROLLS + " times");

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ROLLS; i++)
        {
            //Roll the dice.
            die1.roll();
            die2.roll();

            //Display the value of the dice.
            System.out.println(die1.getValue() + " " + die2.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I need help keeping track of which die wins, out of the 10 rolls and determine if the user wins, the computer wins, or if it's a tie.

Comment: Saying "I need help" isn't helpful unless you tell us *what help you need*. See:
 [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, yet elegant solution that uses a simple while loop and a couple variables to hold the user score, comp score and the total number of wins for each of them.

```
int userWin = 0, compWin = 0;
int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;

while(MAX_ATTEMPTS > 0) {

    int userScore = 0, compScore = 0;
    //Roll the dice for user
    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();
    userScore = die1.getValue() + die2.getValue();

    //Roll the dice for comp
    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();
    compScore = die1.getValue() + die2.getValue();       

    // determine winner
    if (userScore > compScore) {
        System.out.println("User wins! \nUser score = " + userScore + ", Comp score = " + compScore);            
        userWin++;
    }
    else if (userScore < compScore) {
        System.out.println("Comp wins! \nUser score = " + userScore + ", Comp score = " + compScore);
        compWin++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Draw!\nUser score = " + userScore + ", Comp score = " + compScore);
    }

    MAX_ATTEMPTS --;

}
System.out.println("User won = " + userWin + " times! ");  
System.out.println("Comp won = " + compWin + " times! ");
```

Answer (score 1):

One example solution is to initialize two arrays one for the computer one for the user.
Each time you throw a dice you increment the array on position throwing turn number with dice.

```
int [] computer = new int[10];
int [] user = new int [10]; 

for (int i=0;i<10; ++i) {
   int diceUser = throwDice();
   int diceComputer = throwDice();
   if (diceUser> diceComputer) {
      user[i] = diceUser;
   }
   else if (diceUSer<diceComputer) {
      computer[i]= diceComputer;
   }
   else {
      computer[i] = diceComputer;
      user[i] = diceUser;
   }     
}
```

Every time computer or user has lost, they will have 0 in the array. When it is a draw both arrays will contain the same value at the same index.

The index of the array is following the turn.